# Finding minimum and maximum in Java 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, max, min

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and need some help. I need to find the min/max values and print them out for a multidimensional array. Here are the two ways that I have tried.

```
import java.util.*;

class MinMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] data = {{3, 2, 5},
                {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                {9, 1, 0, 2},
                {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8}};
        Arrays.sort(data);
        System.out.println("Minimum = " + data[0]);
        System.out.println("Maximum = " + data[data.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

This version complies but doesn't run.

```
import java.util.*;

class MinMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] data = {{3, 2, 5},
                {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                {9, 1, 0, 2},
                {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8}};

    public static int getMaxValue(int[] numbers) {
        int maxValue = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = numbers[i];
            }
            return maxValue;
            {
                public static int getMinValue (int[] numbers) {
                    int minValue = numbers[0];
                    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                        if (numbers[i] < minValue) {
                            minValue = numbers[i];
                        }
                    }
                return minValue;
            }
```

This version just throws me a bunch of errors in compiling. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly

Comment: In each case you seem to be ignoring the fact that you have an array-of-arrays-of-int. Think about how to iterate visiting each `int` in each `int[]` array in `data`.

Comment: Which version of Java legalised methods inside methods inside methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've kinda fixed your code. Actually your mistake was that you have not been traversing all the cells of your multidimensional array.

So, I've added additional loop into getMinValue/getMinValue methods and fixed array elements addressing.

```
import java.util.*;

class MinMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] data = {
                {3, 2, 5},
                {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                {9, 1, 0, 2},
                {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8}
        };
        System.out.println(getMaxValue(data));
        System.out.println(getMinValue(data));
    }


    public static int getMaxValue(int[][] numbers) {
        int maxValue = numbers[0][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers[j].length; i++) {
                if (numbers[j][i] > maxValue) {
                    maxValue = numbers[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    public static int getMinValue(int[][] numbers) {
        int minValue = numbers[0][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers[j].length; i++) {
                if (numbers[j][i] < minValue ) {
                    minValue = numbers[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
        return minValue ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay I see. Thank you so much! I've been pulling my hairs out on this one

Answer (score 9):

I have a more fun solution using Java 8 :)

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));
int max = stats.getMax();
int min = stats.getMin();
```

It's a different solution than yours, obviously. But it does the same thing. To begin with, we convert the 2D array into a `Stream` of `int`s. In order to do this first we need to call `flatMapToInt`. We do this to stream all the elements in the array in a flat way. Imagine if we just start using a single index to iterate over the whole 2D array. It's something like that. Once we have converted the array into a stream, we will use IntSummaryStatistics in order to reuse the same stream for both min and max.

Comment: Method references are fun: `x -> Arrays.stream(x)` can be simplified to `Arrays::stream`.

Comment: You know what I find really funny. Once I started doing the Java8 thing , some things are just soo... ridiculously simple and require so much less code. I wonder how have we coded before Java 8 ?

Comment: Man that seems so much simpler! I suppose once I get through the beginners stuff i get to have some more fun in the future haha!

Comment: There was a small error in the example that I corrected through the usage of IntSummaryStatistics. @Fanchen Bao pointed out a stream can be consumed only once. Therefore we use IntSummaryStatistics  in order to avoid recreating the same stream for min and max.

Comment: this code didn't work for me, however, a small change and it works by using this: Arrays.stream(gameField).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).summaryStatistics();

Comment: @luckyguy73 this really helped, not sure how Alex got his code to work as I had your same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem is:** You are sorting the array of `int` arrays instead of sorting each individual `int` in each `int` array.

**To solve this:** Loop through each `int` array in the array of `int` arrays.

**Instructions** for finding the maximum and minimum of a 2D `int` array using `Arrays.sort()`:

1. Declare a 2D `int` array to sort called `data`.
2. Declare two `int`s, one to hold the maximum value, the other the minimum value.

   - The initial value of the maximum should be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and the initial value of the minimum should be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to make sure that negative values are handled.
3. Loop through `data` from `0` to `data.length`:

   1. Sort `data[i]`
   2. Check if the first value of `data[i]` is less than the minimum and change it if it is.
   3. Check if the last value of `data[i]` is greater than the maximum and change it if it is.
4. Output your result.

**Example:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] data = {{3, 2, 5},
            {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
            {9, 1, 0, 2},
            {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8} };

        int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            Arrays.sort(data[i]);

            if(data[i][0] < minimum) minimum = data[i][0];
            if(data[i][data[i].length - 1] > maximum) maximum = data[i][data[i].length - 1];
        }

        System.out.println("Minimum = " + maximum);  
        System.out.println("Maximum = " + minimum); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to figure out how to find the values using a 1D array, thanks for the detail on how to declare it for a 2D array!

Answer (score -2):

```java
package array;

public class Max_number {
    
    // 2 5 7 9
    // 3 6 8 1
    
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        int a[][] = {{2,5,7,9},{3,6,8,1}};
        int max=a[0][0];
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) //row
        {
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++) //coloum
            {
                if(a[i][j]>max)
                {
                    max=a[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("maximum number is"+max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, but explain how this answers the question.